# Twilio Programmable Video using a PTZ Camera

Tags: javascript, camera, twilio, webrtc

I am using Twilio Javascript SDK in the Electron app. I want to use the PTZ camera for publishing the video track during the call and use the camera abilities to publish the video accordingly. Is there any such way to perform such actions using the Twilio Programmable Video?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Can you give me some more detail on this PTZ Camera? Is it a camera that is available as an camera input on your computer? What do you mean by the "camera abilities"?

Comment: @philnash I have a USB camera that supports PTZ controls. I need to control the PTZ of this video track. Webrtc requires me to access the stream like this : const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { pan: true, tilt: true, zoom: true }), Twilio embeds this into createLocalTrack. How do I pass PTZ parameters? 
The camera abilities which I meant are zooming and rotating the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When creating tracks to use with Twilio Video, you can either take tracks you have already got via `getUserMedia`:

```
Video.connect(token, { tracks: tracks });
```

Or you can pass any media constraints via the `video` option to the `connect` function:

```
Video.connect(token, { video: { pan: true }});
```